# Unexpected character " error when using console application args as path c#

Tags: c#, path, console-application, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to use my my console application args as path to show all the directories and files in a folder. Those are my command line arguments: "C:\Users\arnec\Documents".
This is my code currently looks like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(args[0]);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(args[0]);‪

        for (int i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(directories[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
        }
    }
```

// this doesn't work, it gives me a: "Unexpected character "" . I get the same result if I add @

But for some reason this does work:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\arnec\Documents");
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\arnec\Documents");
```

Comment: try removing @ from @args[0]

Comment: I get the same result even without the @

Comment: Please post a simple code that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open this file in an hexadecimal editor, you could see at the end of this line:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(args[0]);‪
```

the values:

```
3B -> ;
E2 80 AA -> hidden character
0D 0A -> next line
```

You have to remove this character.

I copy and paste your code in a new console project.

Comment: Jose is correct. Also, You can open the file using Visual Studio -> File ->Open; use open with and select Binary Editor.